# finding GC content of sequences in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, biopython

I have a dataframe df

```
oligo_name  oligo_sequence

AAAAA       attttggggctggtaa

BBBBB       attttcccgaatgtca
```

and so on. To calculate the GC content of each sequence I did the following

```
from Bio.SeqUtils import GC

df['GC content'] = GC(df['oligo_sequence'])
```

but I get the following error :

```
KeyError: 'Level G must be same as name (None)'
```

Can you suggest a fix or a better way to calculate GC content of sequneces in a pandas data frame. Thanks

Comment: Could you try this: `df['GC content'] = df[['oligo_sequence']].apply(lambda row: GC(row), axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
In [23]:

df['GC content'] = df['oligo_sequence'].apply(GC)
df
Out[23]:
  oligo_name    oligo_sequence  GC content
0      AAAAA  attttggggctggtaa       43.75
1      BBBBB  attttcccgaatgtca       37.50
```

You can't pass a Series as a param to a function unless it understands what a pandas Series or the array type is so you can instead call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) and pass the function as the param which will call that function for every value in the Series as shown above.